# Period of continued fraction of $\sqrt{p}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

Few years ago, one of my friends find that $\sqrt{p}$ has periodic continued fraction with odd (resp. even) period iff $p\equiv 1(mod 4)$ (resp. $p\equiv 3(mod 4)$) for a prime $p$. (You can observe this in here : http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C4%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C5%2C4%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C6%2C2&language=english&go=Search). However, I don't know any clues to prove this. He told that it may be related to Pell's equation. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The equation $a^2-Nb^2=-1$ has a solution if and only if the period length of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{N}$ is odd. The equation $a^2-pb^2=-1$ cannot be solved if $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ because that would imply that $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, which is not the case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have an idea how to show that $a^2-pb^2=-1$ has always a solution for $p\equiv 1\mod 4$, which is all we need.

Comment: @Peter there is a short proof for $a^2 - p b^2 = -1$ in Mordell's book Diophantine Equations. pages 55-56

Comment: @WillJagy Then please add this proof or at least the main idea to your answer.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you, this completes the proof.

Comment: There is also this book by Khinchin http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Continued%20Fractions%20Khinchin.pdf 

*THEOREM 28. Every periodic continued fraction represents a quadratic
irrational number and every quadratic irrational number is represented
by a periodic continued fraction.*

E.g. $x^2-p=0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If  prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ there are both (nontrivial) solutions to $x^2 - p y^2 = 1$ and $u^2 - p v^2 = -1.$ If you keep track of the "convergents" $\frac{a}{b}$ while finding the continued fraction, you will actually find $a^2 - p b^2 = -1$ along the way, about halfway.

13

$$
\small  
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 3 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{3}{1} &  &  \frac{4}{1} & &  \frac{7}{2}  & & \frac{11}{3} & &  \frac{18}{5} & &   \frac{119}{33}  & &   \frac{137}{38}  & &   \frac{256}{71}   & &   \frac{393}{109}  & &   \frac{649}{180}   & &   \frac{4287}{1189}  \\
              \\
 & 1 & & -4 &  &  3 & &  -3  & & 4 & &  -1 & &   4  & &   -3  & &   3   & &   -4  & & 1   & &  -4  
\end{array}
$$

29

$$   \sqrt {29}  $$

$$ \scriptsize 
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 5 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 10 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 10 & \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{5}{1} &  &  \frac{11}{2} & &  \frac{16}{3}  & & \frac{27}{5} & &  \frac{70}{13} & &   \frac{727}{135}  & &   \frac{1524}{283}  & &   \frac{2251}{418}   & &   \frac{3775}{701}  & &   \frac{9801}{1820}   & &   \frac{101785}{18901}  \\
              \\
-29 & 1 & & -4 &  &  5 & &  -5  & & 4 & &  -1 & &   4  & &   -5  & &   5   & &   -4  & & 1   & &  -4  
\end{array}
$$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

**THEOREM 1:** With prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ there is always a solution to $$ x^2 - p y^2 = -1  $$ in integers. The proof is from Mordell, Diophantine Equations, pages 55-56.

PROOF: Take the smallest integer pair $T>1,U >0$ such that $$ T^2 - p U^2 = 1. $$
We know that $T$ is odd and $U$ is even. So, we have the integer equation
$$ \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right)  \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = p  \left( \frac{U}{2} \right)^2. $$

We have $$ \gcd \left( \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right),  \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) \right) = 1. $$
Indeed, 
$$  \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) -   \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = 1. $$

There are now two cases, by unique factorization in integers:

$$ \mbox{(A):} \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) = p a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = b^2 $$

$$  \mbox{(B):}  \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) =  a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = p b^2 $$

Now, in case (B), we find that $(a,b)$ are smaller than $(T,U),$ but $T \geq 3, a > 1,$ and $a^2 - p b^2 = 1.$ This is a contradiction, as our hypothesis is that $(T,U)$ is minimal.

As a result, case (A) holds, with evident $$p a^2 - b^2 = \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) - \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = 1, $$
so
$$  b^2 - p a^2 = -1.   $$

$$  \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc $$

**THEOREM 2:** With primes $p \neq q,$ with $p \equiv q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and Legendre $(p|q)=(q|p) = -1,$ there is always a solution to $$ x^2 - pq y^2 = -1  $$ in integers. The proof is from Mordell, Diophantine Equations, pages 55-56.

PROOF: Take the smallest integer pair $T>1,U >0$ such that $$ T^2 - pq U^2 = 1. $$
We know that $T$ is odd and $U$ is even. So, we have the integer equation
$$ \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right)  \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = pq  \left( \frac{U}{2} \right)^2. $$

We have $$ \gcd \left( \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right),  \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) \right) = 1. $$

There are now four cases, by unique factorization in integers:

$$  \mbox{(1):}  \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) =  a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = pq b^2 $$

$$ \mbox{(2):} \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) = p a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = q b^2 $$
$$ \mbox{(3):} \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) = q a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = p b^2 $$
$$ \mbox{(4):} \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) = pq a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) =  b^2 $$

Now, in case (1), we find that $(a,b)$ are smaller than $(T,U),$ but $T \geq 3, a > 1,$ and $a^2 - pq b^2 = 1.$ This is a contradiction, as our hypothesis is that $(T,U)$ is minimal.

In case $(2),$ we have
$$  p a^2 - q b^2 = 1.  $$
$$  p a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod q,    $$ so $a$ is nonzero mod $q,$ then
$$ p \equiv \left( \frac{1}{a} \right)^2 \pmod q.  $$
This contradicts  the hypothesis $(p|q) = -1.$

In case $(3),$ we have
$$  q a^2 - p b^2 = 1.  $$
$$  q a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p,    $$ so $a$ is nonzero mod $p,$ then
$$ q \equiv \left( \frac{1}{a} \right)^2 \pmod p.  $$
This contradicts  the hypothesis $(q|p) = -1.$

As a result, case (4) holds, with evident $$pq a^2 - b^2 = \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) - \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = 1, $$
so
$$  b^2 - pq a^2 = -1.   $$

$$  \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc   \bigcirc $$

**Caution:** With primes $p \neq q,$ with $p \equiv q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and Legendre $(p|q)=(q|p) = 1,$ there may not be a solution to $$ x^2 - pq y^2 = -1  $$
For example, $205 = 5 \cdot 41$ and $221 = 13 \cdot 17.$ Below is the Lagrange-Gauss method for the continued fraction. No decimal accuracy is needed, no memory used in the computer.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 205
0  form   1 28 -9   delta  -3
1  form   -9 26 4   delta  6
2  form   4 22 -21   delta  -1
3  form   -21 20 5   delta  4
4  form   5 20 -21   delta  -1
5  form   -21 22 4   delta  6
6  form   4 26 -9   delta  -3
7  form   -9 28 1   delta  28
8  form   1 28 -9
```

==========================================================

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 221
0  form   1 28 -25   delta  -1
1  form   -25 22 4   delta  6
2  form   4 26 -13   delta  -2
3  form   -13 26 4   delta  6
4  form   4 22 -25   delta  -1
5  form   -25 28 1   delta  28
6  form   1 28 -25
```